# Trying to retrieve the value of a randomly generated PHP string to put in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working with this script to generate a random string:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

I echo the function to show the user the string, but I'm not sure how to place the string in my database.

Comment: could you show this code?

Comment: How do you print your string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the result of the function in a variable:

```
$generated_string = generateRandomString();
```

And save it using a normal query

Comment: I will try this and issue props accordingly. Thank you